# Javascript validation for decimal values range

Tags: javascript, regex, jsp

I am working on JavaScript function.
I need to implement JavaScript function that can validate the floating values that are in range `00000.00` to `99999.99`.

I have used the following JavaScript function:

```
function isDecimal (s) {
    var isDecimal_re     = /^\s*(\+|-)?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))\s*$/;
    return String(s).search (isDecimal_re) != -1;
    }
```

This is validating the Floating values but not working for the range.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know if its possible or not to solve that in one regex, but why don't you do it like that:

```
function isDecimal (s) {
    var isDecimal_re = /^\s*(\+|-)?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))\s*$/;
    return String(s).search (isDecimal_re) != -1 && s > 0.00 && s < 99999.99;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but this is accepting 1.233 i.e 3 precision after decimal which should be validate.

Comment: well you said your regex validates the decimal pattern, so I assumed all you need is the range validation ;) come back with a valid pattern please :)

Comment: Achieved my requirement using the Javascript function        function isDecimal(value)    {
     var RE = /^\d*(\.\d{1})?\d{0,1}$/;
     if(RE.test(value)){
        if(value <= 99999.99)
      return true;
     }else{
        return false;
     }
 }